# Regex for alphanumeric, but at least one letter

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

In my ASP.NET page, I have an input box that has to have the following validation on it:

> Must be alphanumeric, with at least *one* letter (i.e. can't be ALL
> numbers).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Basically this means:

- Zero or more ASCII digits;
- One alphabetic ASCII character;
- Zero or more alphanumeric ASCII characters.

Try a few tests and you'll see this'll pass any alphanumeric ASCII string where at least one non-numeric ASCII character is required.

The key to this is the `\d*` at the front. Without it the regex gets much more awkward to do.

Comment: "One alphanumeric character" should read "One alphabetic character" or similiar: that part of the regex does not include digits.

Comment: @John: not only clever, but efficient! The \d* avoids potential O(N**2) backtracking ... I think.

Comment: Great solution, cletus. You can make the regex a little shorter if you use the case insensitive flag like so: /^\d*[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i

Comment: How you people are able to understand it ? Pls suggest me how to learn it :(

Comment: I found this page to help understand Regex https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html to test the regex use a free online tester https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Answer (score 25):

Most answers to this question are correct, but there's an alternative, that (in some cases) offers more flexibility if you want to change the rules later on:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

This will match any sequence of alphanumerical characters, but only if the first group also matches the whole sequence. It's a little-known trick in regular expressions that allows you to handle some very difficult validation problems.

For example, say you need to add another constraint: the string should be between 6 and 12 characters long. The obvious solutions posted here wouldn't work, but using the look-ahead trick, the regex simply becomes:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12})$
```

Comment: What purpose does the second .* have?

Comment: None :-) It can be safely ommitted.

Comment: I know that this is a very old post but this saved me a lot of time and trouble today.  NOTE: in the second pattern, the second * IS required if you want it to correctly enforce.  Thanks again.

Comment: Note that the second set of parentheses is unneeded for both expressions. In any case, for the second regex above, I salute you most excellent sir!

Comment: That's sick. Thanks, fixed my problem ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me when I had a regex consisting of multiple optional blocks but I still wanted to ensure there was at least one digit being tested. e.g. `^\$?(\d|,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$` > `^(?=.*[0-9].*)\$?(\d|,\d{3})*(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Comment: Thanks, for a more stricter version of alpha numeric regex, I added lookahead in the begining of your RegEx : (?=.*[0-9].*). Now if there is a sequence of alphabets only, there has to be at least one number and vice versa, to become valide alpha numeric word.

Answer (score 5):

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}]*\p{L}[\p{L}\p{N}]*$
```

Explanation:

- `[\p{L}\p{N}]*` matches zero or more Unicode letters or numbers
- `\p{L}` matches one letter
- `[\p{L}\p{N}]*` matches zero or more Unicode letters or numbers
- `^` and `$` anchor the string, ensuring the regex matches the *entire* string. You may be able to omit these, depending on which regex matching function you call.

Result: you can have any alphanumeric string except there's got to be a letter in there somewhere.

`\p{L}` is similar to `[A-Za-z]` except it will include all letters from all alphabets, with or without accents and diacritical marks. It is much more inclusive, using a larger set of Unicode characters. If you don't want that flexibility substitute `[A-Za-z]`. A similar remark applies to `\p{N}` which could be replaced by `[0-9]` if you want to keep it simple. See the [MSDN page on character classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) for more information.

The less fancy non-Unicode version would be

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Comment: \p{N} would match Unicode numbers, such as ① ② . This may come as surprise for some.

Comment: Turning the first part, [\p{L}\p{N}]*, into \p{N}* simplifies the explanation and prevents some back tracking.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[0-9]*[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*$
```

is the regex that will do what you're after. The ^ and $ match the start and end of the word to prevent other characters.  You could replace the [0-9A-z] block with \w, but i prefer to more verbose form because it's easier to extend with other characters if you want.

Add a regular expression validator to your asp.net page as per the tutorial on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx.

Comment: this could contain all numbers, no?

Comment: missed the extra bit about needing at least one character - i've edited to force at least one character

Comment: If you're not capturing, you don't need () except for grouping, and [] makes a fine group. A-z is more than just letters. You probably meant [0-9A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]*

Answer (score 1):

```
^\w*[\p{L}]\w*$
```

This one's not that hard. The regular expression reads: match a line starting with any number of word characters (letters, numbers, punctuation (which you might not want)), that contains one letter character (that's the `[\p{L}]` part in the middle), followed by any number of word characters again.

If you want to exclude punctuation, you'll need a heftier expression:

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}]*[\p{L}][\p{L}\p{N}]*$
```

And if you don't care about Unicode you can use a boring expression:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Comment: @R. Pate: Thanks. It wouldn't be code if it didn't have bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Can be

- any number ended with a character,
- or an alphanumeric expression started with a character
- or an alphanumeric expression started with a number, followed by a character and ended with an alphanumeric subexpression

Comment: Isn't this the same as the top answer? Just with \d replaced with [0-9].

Comment: Well, yes. I didn't see that at the time of posting