# REGEX - validing letter with number OR only letter

Tags: regex

Some days, I try to create a specific regex to validate a simple "Name" field. Yet even today, could not the way I wanted ...

**I would like to validate a field as follows:**

- to write any character A-Z and/or a-z
- to write numbers since she has some character from A-Z and/or a-z.
- do not allow write only numbers

**For example, valid:**

- Only letters: Microsoft Corporation, Asus Technologies, etc...
- Letters and Numbers: Tom 182, James 007 Bond, etc... (numbers can be any character position: XXXXX 98998 XXXX 87 XXX  )

**For example, invalid:**

- 098230983 (only number is invalid!)

**The failure code REGEX: (^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$)|([0-9]*[a-z\ \']+$)**

PS: regex online: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Thanks to all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex for alphanumeric, but at least one character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051989/regex-for-alphanumeric-but-at-least-one-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
^([0-9]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
```

It allows string to start with digits, then it has to contain a letter and after that letter - letters and digits are possible.

Also a question here: what about whitespace characters ? Because in `Microsoft Corporation` there is one.

If it should be possible to match them too try with:

```
^([0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)$
```

Comment: Thank you. Your regex is easier, simpler and easier to understand that my regex. I'm using now is ^([0-9 ]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)$