# javascript regex to warn invalid username

Tags: javascript, regex

these are the conditions for a valid username

1. must contain a-z or A-Z
2. can contain 0-9 anywhere
3. must not allow any other characters

so `a0` and `0a` are valid user names just like `username` and `UserName`. i need a regex for this.

the issue optionally allowing 0-9

**UPDATE**
the problem with regex like `/\w+/i` is it allows username like `000` but in my case it must contain an alphabet and not any special characters

Comment: This is a very simple expression.  What have you tried?

Comment: This has been answered many times on StackOverflow

Comment: @Scott my issue is in optionally allowing [0-9]

Comment: try this /\w+/g

Comment: @RenzoCC this allows `09` as username but it must contain atleast one alphabet

Comment: @ctwheels i searched before asking. I asked because i feel this question is unique. can you provide a link

Comment: @ctwheels that will not work in js

Comment: @HaseebEqx My apologies, you can use `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` and here's a link to an existing question with same conditions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051989/regex-for-alphanumeric-but-at-least-one-character

Comment: yes `/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[\w]+$/.` looks working

Comment: `\w` may not be the best to use here since it allows for `_` and may allow for foreign characters in some languages. Also `[\w]` can be replaced with `\w` as the `[]` is redundant here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex for alphanumeric, but at least one character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051989/regex-for-alphanumeric-but-at-least-one-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the working regex is `/^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[a-zA-Z])+$/`.

it does match `0a` `a0` `aaa`

but will not match `000` or `+a` or `a+`

please read the question completely, before putting down votes

Comment: I have edited my answer and posted regexp that works and is a bit simpler

Comment: Although this does work, the regex I put in my comment `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` will perform with an even number or fewer steps in all cases. The one that @AndrzejSmyk posted will use fewer steps in all cases as well

Answer (score 1):

You don't know how to compose lookahead ? just use

```
var isValid = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(username) && /^[a-zA-Z\d]$/.test(username);
              ^^^^^^^^^ at last one char
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^only char & digits
```

You want to learn lookahead ? Just use:

```
var isValid = /^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]+$/gmi.test(username);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
/^[a-zA-z0-9]*[a-zA-z][a-zA-z0-9]*$/
```

Comment: it allows `user+`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
/^(\d*[a-zA-Z]+\d*)+$/
```

Comment: `[\d]` is the same as `\d`, no need for square brackets `[]`. Also there's an extra `(` at the beginning, so this is invalid