# regular expression to force to have at least one letter and number in a string?

Tags: javascript

I am practicing regular expressions and I need a regular expression to force the user to write at least one number and at least one letter when writing the password. How can I do it? I'm using this:

```
'^[A-Za-z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$'
```

and it does not work. this pattern is not fulfilled, I only introduce numbers and it does not require to have at least one letter.

In my real code I use:

```
 Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$')
```

For example I need validate the string

```
123456789a
```

And not works

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051989/regex-for-alphanumeric-but-at-least-one-character

Comment: Use two regular expressions: `/[a-z]/i.test(password) && /\d/.test(password)` should enforce at least one letter and one number.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks.. that not works for me.. In mi case I use "123456789a' and not works..

Comment: @yavg works fine for me: `var password = '123456789a'; /[a-z]/i.test(password) && /\d/.test(password) // returns true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex pattern to match at least 1 number and 1 character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684815/regex-pattern-to-match-at-least-1-number-and-1-character-in-a-string)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts apologize that message was not for you, in my real code I do not think you can put 2 conditions as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/`

I hope it's helps ;)

Comment: it returns true to me: var expression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;

console.log(expression.test("123456789a"));