# Regex for the specific chars at least appear once

Tags: regex

I have a requirement that validates the user input.

- only input `a-z`,`A-Z`, `'`, '-' and blanks.
- `a-z`,`A-Z` should appear at least once.

In other words:

- 'test user' --> True
- 'test1user' --> False
- ' test user' -' --> True
- '   ' --> False
- ' ' - '  --> False

I tried one way like `^[(A-Za-z)? '-]+$`, but not work.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Try ['\\- ]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z'\\- ]*

Comment: Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055579/3832970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead condition to ensure there must be at least one letter in input:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[A-Za-z '-]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pR0Upy/1)

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` is a [positive lookahead condition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts presence of at least one letter in input text.